What is the reading of the kanji for "small octopus"?
What is the reading of the kanji for "small octopus"?
I read the discussion of octopus kanji here
Octopus kanji: 章魚 vs 蛸 vs 鮹
but there was no mention of small ones, such as in the wikipedia page about the Hokusai print here
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/蛸と海女
where one finds
小【しょう】蛸【たこ】の方【ほう】からは口吸【くちす】い【接吻【せっぷん】】を受【う】け...
(furigana generated by https://www.jcinfo.net/en/tools/kana)
She receives a kiss on the mouth from the small octopus...
I am asking since there are many ways to read the kanji for "small":
小 [音] ショウ  [訓] ちい.さい こ- お- さ-  [名] いさら こう さざ しゃお ちいさ
Is the reading 小【しょう】蛸【たこ】 correct?

大 before the name of an animal/plant is usually read using the kun-reading おお:

オオサンショウウオ
オオイヌノフグリ

Therefore, 大蛸 is certainly read おおだこ. (Note that たこ is voiced due to rendaku.)
One might be tempted to think 小 should also be read with the kun-reading, こ, but this doesn't work quite well. The こ prefix is usually associated with a different kanji, 子:

子犬 = こいぬ (not 小犬)
子イルカ = こいるか ("child dolphin" rather than "small dolphin")

Actually, despite its simple appearance, a word like 小蛸 is uncommon, and even native speakers might feel somewhat uncomfortable if asked to read it aloud. But if I really had to read it, I would probably say こだこ. If possible, I might rephrase it as 小さな蛸 so that listeners wouldn't misinterpret it as "child octopus". Some may read it as しょうだこ, and I cannot say it's correct or wrong...

多くは「子」なのね・・確かに「小鳥」と「小魚」しかないっぽいわ

@chocolate むしろ「小鳥」は思いついてませんでした。確かにあれは子鳥じゃないですね…

I'm not 100% sure but I would read...
[大蛸]{おおだこ} ・ [小蛸]{こだこ}

The important word is "usually," since there is also...
新潟市の水族館　海岸で見つかったダイオウイカを見せる
Niigata City aquarium displays giant squid found on the coast
https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10012956291000/k10012956291000.html
...which leads me to avoid generalizations and just memorize individual words as I come across them.

@Ned, あ、ダイオウイカは、普通に、「[大王]{だいおう}」(=great king) +「[烏賊]{いか}」なので。（「[大大]{だいおお}イカ」じゃないですよｗ）

あ、なるほどね！ありがとう！
